# Enzyme does not return child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I am trying to test my component with Enzyme mount.

But I do not get my child component.

This code does not work:

```
it('contains an <TransmissorRow/> component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(TransmissorRow)).to.have.length(2);
});
```

I got this error:

AssertionError: expected { Object (component, root, ...) } to have a length of 2 but got 0

I have 2 TransmissorRow at my component ()

I logged wrapper.find(TransmissorRow).debug() and I got this:

```
[▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․]
  [▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬]
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is TransmissorRow rendered directly in the wrapper or inside a child component of the wrapper?
Could you attach your `wrapper.debug()` log? Maybe try to replace shallow with mount (Didn't say which you used)

Comment: I edit my question and put there there debug

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, my wrapper.debug() has not TransmissorRow

Comment: I set my props wrong, I fixed and worked. Thanks